# problem odoo 13 and odoo12 not work but odoo11 working

Tags: installation, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

Welcome. I have a problem. I installed UDO 11, 12 and 13 in Ubuntu 18, Odo 11 works fine and it is the first to install it, but Odo 12 and 13 I face a problem when I run the file. I will review what concerns the three copies.

---

my ubuntu user is 'mamado'
and create user same name in posgresql and make password '123'

---

odoo11 working
write command

```
 ./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons,custom_addons
```

working

---

odoo12
file config is odoo_12.conf   content is

---

```
[options]
addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo-12.0/addons
admin_passwd = $pbkdf2-sha512$25000$H2OslZLyHmMMIWQM4dw7Zw$oPz36FY95KMkRALFKwHdJsICkGEaxjvikGr8F6yVgqQR8jd2RwMfmAnXziMwMtLTCXkguSn8WcrEUKjvhFJKSg
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /home/mamado/.local/share/Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = False
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template1
db_user = mamado
dbfilter = 
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8072
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo12/odoo_12.log
logrotate = False
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = None
pidfile = False
proxy_mode = False
reportgz = False
server_wide_modules = web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_commit = False
test_enable = False
test_file = False
test_report_directory = False
test_tags = None
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
without_demo = False
workers = 0
```

#############################

---

write in terminal command is

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons --xmlrpc-port=8092 --config=/etc/odoo_12.conf
```

> 

```
     File "/home/mamado/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py",
> line 127, in connect
>         conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>     psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied - - -
```

---

odoo13
file config is odoo13.conf   content is

---

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
;admin_passwd = PASSWORD
db_host = 127.0.0.1
db_port = 5432
db_user = mamado
db_password = 123
addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo-13.0/addons
http_port = 8092
;Log Settings
logfile = /var/log/odoo13/odoo_13.log
;log_level = error
####################################
```

---

write in terminal command is

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons --xmlrpc-port=8092 --config=/etc/odoo13.conf
```

error of odoo 13  is

> 

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column ir_ui_view.arch_updated does
> not exist LINE 1: ...pe" as "type","ir_ui_view"."arch_fs" as
> "arch_fs","ir_ui_vie...
```

---

in browser both is show

**Internal Server Error**

Comment: are you installing odoo for development purpose ??

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:
1- you didn't provide odoo-12 config with db_password while you put it 123 in odoo-11 config.

2- try to open odoo-12 in incognito-window or a different browser.

3- if still not working try to run odoo-12 with a newest version of postgres.

Comment: Hello dear, thank you very much, but I found a solution a while ago, which is creating a new database using commands

./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons --xmlrpc-port=8095 -c /etc/odoo13.conf -d database