# Restoring db in odoo 14

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, restore, odoo-14

Facing an error in **Odoo 14** during the restoring process and also while running the server on the terminal.

Surprisingly it can run on the **web**, just can't proceed with the login with an error when doing the same.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 946, in web_login
    uid = request.session.authenticate(request.session.db, request.params['login'], request.params['password'])
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 1025, in authenticate
    uid = odoo.registry(db)['res.users'].authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/addons/website/models/res_users.py", line 70, in authenticate
    uid = super(ResUsers, cls).authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 713, in authenticate
    uid = cls._login(db, login, password, user_agent_env=user_agent_env)
doo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 101, in check
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 300, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 806, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/addons/website/controllers/main.py", line 140, in web_login
    return super().web_login(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 946, in web_login
    uid = request.session.authenticate(request.session.db, request.params['login'], request.params['password'])
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 1025, in authenticate
    uid = odoo.registry(db)['res.users'].authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/addons/website/models/res_users.py", line 70, in authenticate
    uid = super(ResUsers, cls).authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 713, in authenticate
    uid = cls._login(db, login, password, user_agent_env=user_agent_env)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 690, in _login
    if tz in pytz.all_timezones and (not user.tz or not user.login_date):
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/fields.py", line 1021, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/fields.py", line 555, in _compute_related
    record[self.name] = self._process_related(value[self.related_field.name])
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 5694, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 3071, in _fetch_field
    self._read(fnames)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 3138, in _read
    cr.execute(query_str, params + [sub_ids])
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in execute
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 101, in check
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/usr/oishi_odoo14/odoo/sql_db.py", line 300, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column res_partner.gender does not exist
LINE 1: ..."res_partner"."company_size2" as "company_size2", "res_partn...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "res_partner.index".
```

I've tried various solutions on web with the error specified, but still couldn't resolve the error.

- Anyone experienced a similar issues?, if do then
- how come you resolved the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First approach for this issue is: to re-create the custom-field: (example: "res_partner.gender") in your custom module, in the corresponding model which _inherit=res_partner...

Another approach:
I had a similar problem, because i had delete a custom-field from a model, but this field was still used in a view.
I could solve it by desactivating the concerned view(s) containing my custom field (website.mycustomfield) using p.SQL request:

1. To identify the concerned views:

```sql
    SELECT public.ir_ui_view
    WHERE arch_db like '%website.mycustomfield%'
```

2. To desactivate the concerned views:

```sql
    UPDATE public.ir_ui_view
    SET active = false
    WHERE arch_db like '%website.mycustomfield%'
```

Other insights into this issue:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zXnlycSXog
- https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/undefined-column-in-employees-module-182628
- [Can't install own custom modules in Odoo 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275736/cant-install-own-custom-modules-in-odoo-13)
- [PostgreSQL: column does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544933/postgresql-column-does-not-exists)
- [problem odoo 13 and odoo12 not work but odoo11 working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435969/problem-odoo-13-and-odoo12-not-work-but-odoo11-working)

Comment: Ahh i see! Actually the error was fixed by another dev at my company but thanks a lot for telling me!!

Comment: thanks for reply and up-lift ^